# Prevent repetitive terms in get_the_term_list

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, terms

I've created a custom taxonomy 'work_category' for a custom post type 'works'. Then I added 5 new work categories and assigned them to every single 'work'. I've used `get_the_term_list` to print out a list of all the work categories.

Now, certain works have multiple categories assigned to them due to which the result of `get_the_term_list` includes the repeated ones too. How do I prevent that from happening?

The current result is:

```
All
E-Commerce
Web Design and Development
Hosting and Cloud Services
Data Processing and Automation
Custom Software / Applications
E-Commerce
Web Design and Development
```

*Notice 'E-Commerce' & 'Web Design and Development' are repeated.*

---

**Update**

Also tried the following method using `wp_get_object_terms` which too yielded similar result.

```
$work_terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'work_category');
foreach( $work_terms as $term ){
    echo '<li><a href="#">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
}
```

Comment: But these terms have all different slugs?

Comment: No, they have the same slug

Comment: I might be misunderstanding something, I'm just confused how you can have duplicated terms on a single post ;-) I understand that the term names can be duplicated but not the term slugs.

Comment: Not on the single post, on the custom template page where I'm fetching them works. This is a WIP screenshot, if it helps: http://imgur.com/PAy3IdM

Comment: Can you share the relevant code? Are you combining multiple `get_the_term_list` outputs together?

Comment: `get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'work_category', '<li>', '', '</li>' )`

Comment: and are all these terms (the list above) coming from a single call to `get_the_term_list` ?

Comment: Yes there's only one call.

Comment: Why do you assume "works have multiple categories assigned" is the reason if you retrieve the list for one specific post (`$post->ID`) ?

Comment: Based on the current result. There are 5 works assigned to a single different category and a 6th assigned two categories. Hence, the repeated E-Commerce and Web Design & Development